# Mondrian Error:Internal error: No server instance has id

Tags: sql-server, instance, mondrian, saiku

Yesterday, mondrian gave me this error:

> Mondrian Error:Internal error: No server instance has id 'Test2'

I was trying to connect to a remote SQLSERVER with multiple instance. 
This is my connection url:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://instanciados/TestDB;instance=BENDER2
```

I tried with lot of urls and drivers, but i could not find a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Mondrian issue. You can probably reproduce this with a simple Java program which establishes a JDBC connection. I suggest reviewing the SQL Server JDBC documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
            "jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=XYZ; Catalog=C:/Servers/saiku/saiku-server/saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/test.xml; JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;jdbc.username=sa;jdbc.password=sadmin";
```

It works!